# Why adding (by typing in code) an object to NSArray freezes my app?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, nsarray

I am in dead end. I have **UITableViewCell** class that is used as "Settings" tab in my application. The cells are created and counted like this:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.refreshControl = nil;
    self.tableView.separatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleNone;
    self.tableView.scrollEnabled = NO;
```

(...) Note that Title 4 is commented

```
NSArray* titles = @[ @"Title1", @"Title2", @"Title3"/*,@"Title4"*/];

    for (int i = 0; i < titles.count; i++)
    {
        SettingsTableCell* cell = [[SettingsTableCell alloc] initWithFrame: CGRectMake(0, 0, self.tableView.frame.size.width, self.tableView.frame.size.height / titles.count)];
        cell.textLabel.text = [titles objectAtIndex:i];
        cell.textLabel.numberOfLines = -1;
        cell.backgroundColor = i % 2 == 0 ? [Colors colorForType:kLegiaColorWhite] : [UIColor whiteColor];
        cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
        cell.textLabel.font = [Fonts fontWithSize: IPHONE_IPAD(18.0, 24.0)];
        cell.accessoryView = i == 0 ? calendarSwitch : (i == 1 ? scheduleFilterSwitch : wifiSwitch);

        [cells addObject:cell];
    }
}
```

I think down below everything is correct

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [cells count];
}

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return self.tableView.frame.size.height / [self tableView:tableView numberOfRowsInSection:indexPath.section];
}

- (UITableViewCell*)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return [cells objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
}
```

Please note that the problem occurs when I uncomment fourth title in my array. 
When I enter into Settings tab it's starting to loop itself (I checked in debugger) and app rather freezes than crashes. With three titles it works like a charm. Could You help me finding why?

EDIT:

After @Avi suggested, I put breakpoint on `heightForRowAtIndexPath` and it loops on this specific method. In debugger I have this:
[image: StackView]

Comment: What is the crash log? That should be helpful.

Comment: what is you tableview hieght and width?

Comment: And your way to implement table view is ...weird, by the way

Comment: height for row at index method is wierd too, why dont u simply use height/array.count ?

Comment: are u adding the objects on view did load ?

Comment: Can two cells have the same accessoryView?

Comment: It's almost certainly your implementation of one of the delegate methods that triggers recursion.  Break in the debugger and look at the stack trace.  My guess as to the culprit is your implementation of `heightForRowAtIndexPath`.

Comment: Edited my answer and added an screenshot

Comment: That's not how you create cells. You are setting yourself up for all kinds of problems. Implement cellForRowAtIndexPath properly, as hundreds of thousands of developers do. What you are doing is wrong, wrong, wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After researching and reducing items in `*titles` array (it worked for 1 and 2 items), I noticed that every cell had it own UISwitch, and 4th one doesn't have, as it is not needed. And layout subviews couldn't complete because of this error.
So I changed the following line:

```
   cell.accessoryView = i == 0 ? calendarSwitch : (i == 1 ? scheduleFilterSwitch : wifiSwitch);
```

to that one

```
cell.accessoryView = i == 0 ? calendarSwitch : (i == 1 ? scheduleFilterSwitch : i == 2 ? wifiSwitch : nil);
```

I worked!
Help You guys for help!